# TFS wrong Clone URL but right connection?

Tags: git, tfs

Hi My issue is fairly simple and yet I do not know how to change it.

I've got a TFS server setup with with an address similar to https://someUrl.dk/TFS
works when I go to edge or chrome and I can log in and work on it from there no problems.

But when I go to the https://someUrl.dk/TFS/DSSCollection/_git/SomeProject

and click the clone button the clone repo commandline looks like this:

http://computername:8080/tfs/DSSCollection/_git/SomeProject

how do I change so it will report the correct clone url..
to add a little wringle on this. When I go to Visual studio and connect to the server there is the same issue the connection runs on the someUrl.dk but the clone repo still reports to the computername:8080 I would love for that to change to the correct one too.. what is is I am missing ?

Comment: The clone command success with the different URL?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes if I use the correct clone url. but Visual studio see the wrong one and doesn't allow me to change it. and I cannot ask our clients to manually change the url behind Visual studio as they are using visual studio to handle all of their Git operations.

Comment: clone with this url `http://computername:8080/tfs/DSSCollection/_git/SomeProject` working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to your app tier configuration.

The process to update it varies slightly from version to version, but it will definitely involve logging into your application tier server and using the [Administration Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/open-admin-console). There will probably be a "Change URLs" or "Update URLs" option for your application tier.

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer (which did not deserve a downvote) +1

Comment: I've added your answer as the correct one as it is very close to what I did the problem I had was to find the Change URL option but it was hidden behind some permisions that I just got today.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the URL is the wrong one, or how to change it at the remote side level when clicking on clone.

But as a workaround, you can try:

```
git config --global url."http://computername:8080/tfs/".insteadOf https://someurl.dk/TFS/
```

That should be enough to force Git using the right URL.

Comment: this is a fine fix if it was only me who is having the issue but the problem here is that we are quite a few that have the issue and some out of the house I cannot go to out clients and say because we have an issue that they should perform this workaround. especially once we roll this out to twice as many as we are now. 

but thanks for your contribution as this is a nice little hack that might help others in similar situations.

Comment: @Helbo Agreed. I wasn't aware of your context. I suspect a fix in the server configuration is needed to actually fix the URL.